# PHP create a nicer way to echo variables

Tags: php, variables, replace

I am looking for a way to replace `<?php echo $something; ?>` with another notation like `{$something}`. But: No smarty or sth similar is used!

More detailed:
At the moment, I got a .php file (with some variables inside), which includes the file "template.php". In this template file, I don't want having to use the (not very user-friendly) php notation, but replace certain strings inside this file like mentioned above. Is there any way to do so? It would be probably the best, if you could replace strings like `<title></title>` with  `<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>`.

Maybe (my thoughts) I should just write the whole code into a php variable, then do some preg_replace and echo it? Or is there a more beautiful solution?

Comment: Short tags? `<?=$something?>`. You're preg_replace, echo solution is basically smarty/twig. Personally, I've never understood why php templates need to be 'user friendly'.

Comment: Short tags don't really help - I wanna create a template system for total newbies and coding-lazy people :) But if smarty uses a similar solution, there shouln't be a problem...

Comment: smarty is only one of many templateing engines

Comment: @MikeB: because people wanna template while they're templating their templates in the php templating engine. Why only have one layer of templating, when you have two at only 4x the cost?

Comment: @Pi_isnt_42: PHP **IS** a templating engine. It always has been. You're just laying more complexity on top of what's already a pretty complex system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a similar thing several years ago wherein I had to replace several variables in an email template. What I ended up implementing was doing a `str_replace` on several tags. Like you, I don't want to have PHP notations or to escape characters in the template file as much as possible

Example:

template.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>[EMAIL_TITLE]</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello [USER_NAME],

        Login here [LOGIN_LINK].
    </body>
</html>
```

processor.php

```
$body = file_get_contents( 'template.php' );

str_replace( '[EMAIL_TITLE]', $emailTitle, $body );
str_replace( '[USER_NAME]', $userName, $body );
str_replace( '[LOGIN_LINK]', $userName, $body );
```

I've sinced changed implementation though to make use of PHP short tags. Using the same previous example, you could try:

template.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?= $params['title']; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello <?= $params['userName']; ?>!
    </body>
</html>
```

processor.php

```
$params = array(
    'title' => $siteTitle,
    'userName' => $userName
);

ob_start();
require_once( 'template.php' );
$body = ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few notations you can try. One that I prefer for templates is simply:

```
<?php

echo <<<HTML
<html>
    <head>
        <title>$title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        $body
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

?>
```

And then in your content file, you do something like:

```
<?php
$title = 'My Page!';
$body = '<p>My Content!</p>';
include './template.php';
?>
```

With this, you don't have to escape singe and double quotes, and it's easy to make changes later.

You can also read in the file to a string and use preg_replace like you said. The easiest way would be with an array to manually go through the file and pull out the place holders. But this is a slow solution if you have high traffic and a lot of variables.

Comment: Ok, thank you! In fact, I have 4 variables, so this shouldn't be a problem :) I will try both solutions (your and preg_replace) and see what's the best/easiest.

Comment: Since the question is "PHP create a nicer way to echo variables" and the explanation on his question, this is not an answer, cause that he is trying to use is a new notation, then is no PHP, then the answer is related to a template engine, however that is not an answer, or the user who ask must rewrite his answer

Comment: Fair comment, but the underlying question I took was what is a clean, efficient way to output template variables. I agree that even <?=$var?> can be tedious.